# CLBeacon - how to change rssi, major and minor?

Tags: objective-c, core-location, ibeacon

My question is basically - how do I get to modify iBeacon's default settings like major, minor and RSSI?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are different ways to set these values depending on what you mean by an iBeacon:

1. Hardware iBeacons

   Each Beacon vendor has different ways of setting these values.  Some are changed via a bluetooth service that is typically managed with a proprietary iOS or Android app.  (Examples include [Radius Networks](http://www.radiusnetworks.com)' battery-powered and USB beacons and [TwoCanoes beacons](http://twocanoes.com/bleu).)  Radius Networks' [PiBeacon](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/ibeacon-development-kit.html) includes an SD card with an [editable file](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/ibeacon-development-kit-instructions.html) containing the identifiers. Other vendors like Estimote create beacons with fixed UUIDs that cannot be changed.  Because there is no standard mechanism, there is no universal tool for setting identifiers on all beacon types.
2. iOS Software iBeacons:

   You set these values with code like below:

   ```
   CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"] major:1 minor:1 identifier:@"com.radiusnetworks.iBeaconExample"];
   NSDictionary *peripheralData = [region peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:-55];
   [_peripheralManager startAdvertising:peripheralData];
   ```
3. The iOS `CLBeacon` class

   The `CLBeacon` class is not designed to be created or modified by the user -- it is supposed to be constructed by `CoreLocation` when it detects iBeacons.  That said, you *can* force writing to its read-only properties using KVO syntax like so:

   ```
   CLBeacon * iBeacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
   [iBeacon setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"major"];
   [iBeacon setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"minor"];
   [iBeacon setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-55] forKey:@"rssi"];
   [iBeacon setValue:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"] forKey:@"proximityUUID"];
   NSLog(@"I constructed this iBeacon manually: %@", iBeacon);
   ```

   However, if you are forcing the `CLBeacon` class to be used in ways it was not designed to be used that might mean you are doing something wrong.

Full disclosure: I work for Radius Networks.

Comment: how can i do that if want to set accuracy and proximity?

Comment: It depends on your use case, but you might try subclassing.  Might be worth a new question with details of what you are doing.

Comment: @davidgyoung : I want to change the major minor values of a beacon from iOS code. I got that I should work on 3rd point. But can you please tell me where to add the code given in 3rd point?

Comment: @davidgyoung: To add more, I want to change major, minor values of hardware beacon. Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, you cannot do that from iOS CoreLocation APIs.  To change the identifiers on hardware you must use a configuration tool provided by the hardware vendor.  Each vendor does this a different way.

Comment: Can you create a software AltBeacon on Android?

Comment: @davidgyoung following on front point 1 above - is there no method for creating a generic ibeacon configuration app which will allow one to set uuid/major/minor for beacons from multiple vendors?

Comment: It is certainly possible to make such an app that works with many popular vendors.   But you will need to write separate code for connecting with each vendor's beacon, because there is not a standard way of doing this.  And some vendors do not publish a bluetooth config API, so these will require reverse engineering, and updates each time the vendor changes the private API.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize a CLBeaconRegion object you can specify Major and Minor variables. Took a look at initWithProximityUUID:major:minor:identifier method.

As far as am aware ones a beacon active your cannot change it value unless you recreate that object. Rssi represents signal strength of the beacon which is only read-only and depends on the environment.

Here the link for the (documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeaconRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013054)