# Beacon not scanning above 2 meter

Tags: android, android-ibeacon

I'm doing ibeacon scanning app and i'm using Altbeacon library. My app scanning beacon devices but not scanning more than 2 metre. why? and How to change the scanning distance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964761/all-beacons-are-not-shown-in-android-using-altbeacon-library

Comment: Two meters sounds very low, but usually the beacon's transmitting power can be adjusted and the lower it is, the shorter is the distance from where a phone can detect the beacon. Configuring the transmitting power of course depends on the exact beacon type. The manufacturer probably provides a configuration app. or something like that.

Comment: It is not working but thanks for your replay jaydroider